# How to read token from Flutter Secure Storage in Dio function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have an async function to read token from the Flutter Secure Storage package as follows:

```
readSecureData(String key) async {
    String? data = await storage.read(key: key);
    return data;
  }
```

and I have a function for factoring dio:

```
  static Dio? dio;

  Dio getDio()  {
    if (dio == null) {
      String? token = "";

      SecureStorage()
          .readSecureData("login_token")
          .then((value) => token = value);

      var headers = {
        'Accept': ApiConst.applicationJson,
        'Content-Type': ApiConst.applicationJson,
        'Authorization': "Bearer ${token ?? ''}"
      };

      Duration timeOut = const Duration(seconds: 4);

      BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: ApiConst.apiBaseUrl,
        headers: headers,
             );

      dio = Dio(options);    
      return dio!;
    } else {
      return dio!;
    }
  }
```

so I use the following code

```
String? token = "";
          SecureStorage()
              .readSecureData("login_token")
              .then((value) => token = value);
```

to store token and pass it post header,
but I cannot get the token with this method and it returns empty.

So my question is how to fetch token from  Flutter Secure Storage and pass it in the dio header with above code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String? token = "";
SecureStorage()
  .readSecureData("login_token")
  .then((value) => token = value);
```

with

```
String? token = await SecureStorage().readSecureData("login_token");
```

Because you are invoking other logic outside of the `then` callback,

The code below `readSecureData` will be executed immediately after the `readSecureData` method is called, without waiting for the future to complete.